# Display the list of attachments in a lightning component - download attachment

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, attachment

I need to display th elist of the attachment of a case in a lightning component.

Here is the lightning component :

```
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" required="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="files" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div class="LC11Container" aura:id="listFiles">

    <c:fileUpload parentId="{!v.recordId}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.files}" var="currentFile">

        <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!currentFile.Name}">
            <a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+currentFile.Id}">{!currentFile.Name}</a>
        </h3>
</aura:iteration>
</div>
```

The javascript controller of the component :

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var vAction = component.get("c.getAllFiles");
    console.log('############# component.get("v.recordId") : ' + component.get('v.recordId'));
    vAction.setParams(
    {
        pCaseId : component.get('v.recordId')
    });
    vAction.setCallback(this, function(pResponse) {
        var vState = pResponse.getState();
        if (vState === "SUCCESS") { 
            component.set('v.files', pResponse.getReturnValue());
            console.log(pResponse.getReturnValue());
        } else {
            var vErrors = pResponse.getError();
            if (vErrors) {
                if (vErrors[0] && vErrors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + vErrors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(vAction);
},
```

And the apex controller, that query the attachments and return a wrapper class :

```
public class Doc {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name;
    @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime fileDate;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fileId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fileType;
} 

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Doc> getAllFiles(String pCaseId) {
    List<Doc> vDocs = new List<Doc>();

    List<Attachment> lAtt = [Select Id, Name, ContentType, LastModifiedDate, BodyLength
                            from Attachment 
                            where ParentID=:pCaseId];


    for(Attachment att : lAtt){
        Doc vDoc = new Doc();
        vDoc.fileId = att.Id;
        vDoc.name = att.Name;
        vDoc.fileType = att.ContentType;
        vDoc.fileDate = att.LastModifiedDate;

        vDocs.add(vDoc);
    }

    System.debug('### vDocs : ' + vDocs);

    return vDocs;
}
```

So this display me a list of attachments (the names)  but when I click it it displays the document but did not downoload it or allow me to chose to download it on close it. It juste display the document and I can't even close it without return to last page with the browser.

Can I display link to download the document ?

Comment: why cant you  try "lightning:fileUpload"???

Comment: Because I have to work with attachments and not files ... I know that there is better to work with files but for now I havn't the choice unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set the `download="{!attachment.Name}"` on the link. Without it, the browser will treat it as a page, and not a file.

Answer (score 0):

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" required="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="files" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

```
<c:fileUpload parentId="{!v.recordId}"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.files}" var="currentFile">
    

        <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!currentFile.name}">
            <a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+currentFile.fileId}">{!currentFile.name}</a>
        </h3>
    </aura:iteration>
```